# Can you explain the terminology in a GraphQL POST request

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo

In the Apollo Developers documentation there is an example for a valid body of a post request in GraphQL

```
{
    "query": "query aTest($arg1: String!) { test(who: $arg1) }"
}
```

From what I have seen in Apollo Server this query would also work with:

```
{
    "query": "aTest($arg1: String!) { test(who: $arg1) }"
}
```

Could someone please explain why "query" appears twice in the first example? What does the GraphQL server interpret from this?

Is the second example a standardised format?

Ref: http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-server/requests.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query can have two meanings in GraphQL -- it can refer to the request being made to the server, or to to the type of operation used within that request. There are three types of operations used in GraphQL -- Query, Mutation and Subscription.

In your first example, the first `query` identifies the *query document* being sent with your request. The second `query` identifies the type of operation.

In other words, you can *query* a server, but your query may or may not contain a Query (it may, for example, be a Mutation).

When writing your query, if you omit the type of operation, GraphQL simply assumes you wanted a Query, not some other operation and rolls with it. In a similar fashion, it's possible to omit the *operation name* (`aTest`) as well.

AFAIK, there's no benefit to omitting the operation name -- you should always include it to prevent any ambiguity and potential issues down the line.